# Java Source code translator

Tags: java, debugging, javassist, build-tools

Is there any source code translator which translates a given source code into javassist compatible code. For example, I understand javassist cannot intercept final methods. The translator should be able to translate a final class into functional equivalent non final class.

I understand that this is not right way to ask such question. But I couldnt find any javassist interest forumn. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: look at i18n library: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/

Comment: @sgrillon So, I need to write custom source code java-to-java translator